# PHP CLI на Windows 10 не срабатывает max_execution_time

Tags: php, windows-10, phpunit, консоль, cakephp

Столкнулся с проблемой: на Windows 10, не срабатывает `max_execution_time` для PHP CLI (любых версий, но на данный момент работаю с 5.6).

На сколько мне известно для CLI это значение должно устанавливаться на 0 автоматически. Так и происходит, на на деле выводит ошибку.
Вот фрагменты вывода `php -i`

```bsh
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.6.5

System => Windows NT DESKTOP-LBJCG55 6.2 build 9200 (Windows 8 Business Edition) AMD64
...
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
...
```

Настройка нужна для тестирования кода в cakephp (phpunit).

Вот пример ошибки:

```bsh
Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in...
```

Далее указаны файл и строка, но они каждый раз разные, в зависимости от того в какой момент истекло время выполнения.

PHP установлен вручную (Через "Переменные среды..."), пытался менять значение для `max_execution_time` в `php.ini` и непосредственно в проекте. Результат то-же.

Comment: для консоли отдельный ini файл

Comment: @teran, Где он расположен? В директории с PHP только один `.ini` файл и тот нужно было переименовывать при установке?

Comment: А прокси какой?

Comment: похоже где-то еще время выполнения задается. Попробуйте просто долгий скрипт , без чужого кода, запустить - что будет?

Comment: Дело в том что я в коде вызывал информацию о php и мне отобразило `max_execution_time => 0 => 0` и подключённых `php.ini`, помимо того, который в директории php нету. Ранее я chocolatey использовал, и возможно устанавливал через него php (системе уже пару лет, весь софт не вспомню), может ли конфликтовать?